# Thunderbird STARTTLS fails connecting to Cyrus-IMAP 2.2.13

Tags: imap, thunderbird, starttls

Today all of a sudden my Icedove mail clients (38.7.0) ceased working using STARTTLS after I renewed the server certificate. Plain text IMAP works fine.

The server logs `STARTTLS negotiation failed` for each TLS connection attempt. Analyzing the connection with wireshark shows that the client sends a fatal Bad Certificate alert as response to Server Hello.

However, `openssl s_client -starttls imap -crlf -connect 'imap.example.com:143'-CAfile /etc/certs/cacert.pem` works just fine. The CA is imported into the certificate store of icedove, otherwise icedove closes with Certificate Unknown.

I'm currently looking for means to find out what exactly iceweasel is complaining about.

**Update:** I had the idea to import the certificate as server certificate immediately. Importing worked without complaints and it is registered in icedove's store. But the error persists.

**More Info:** I found that thunderbird can generate debugging information. So I tried: `NSPR_LOG_MODULES=all:5 NSPR_LOG_FILE=/tmp/icedove-imap.log icedove`. The following data is grepped for the thread performing the TLS negotiation and trimmed around the actual negotiation:

```
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: ReadNextLine [stream=777e4b00 nb=16 needmore=0]
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: 784a2000:imap.example.com:NA:CreateNewLineFromSocket: 1 OK Completed
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: 784a2000:imap.example.com:NA:SendData: 2 STARTTLS
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: OOO WriteSegments [this=79470ee0 count=12]
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: OOO rolling back write cursor 14 bytes
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: OOO advancing write cursor by 12
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: STS dispatch [7f04777e4f10]
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: THRD(7f048d802740) Dispatch [7f04777e4f10 0]
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: EVENTQ(7f048d8027a8): notify
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: III ReadSegments [this=777e4b00 count=4096]
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: III pipe input: waiting for data
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: III pipe input: woke up [status=0 available=32]
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: III advancing read cursor by 32
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: ReadNextLine [stream=777e4b00 nb=32 needmore=0]
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: 784a2000:imap.example.com:NA:CreateNewLineFromSocket: 2 OK Begin TLS negotiation now
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: 784a2000:imap.example.com:NA:SendData: 3 capability
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: OOO WriteSegments [this=79470ee0 count=14]
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: OOO rolling back write cursor 12 bytes
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: OOO advancing write cursor by 14
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: STS dispatch [7f04777e4f10]
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: THRD(7f048d802740) Dispatch [7f04777e4f10 0]
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: EVENTQ(7f048d8027a8): notify
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: III ReadSegments [this=777e4b00 count=4096]
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: III pipe input: waiting for data
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: III pipe input: woke up [status=805a1f76 available=0]
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: ReadNextLine [stream=777e4b00 nb=0 needmore=1]
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: 784a2000:imap.example.com:NA:CreateNewLineFromSocket: clearing IMAP_CONNECTION_IS_OPEN - rv = 805a1f76
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: THRD(7f04a30fe690) Dispatch [7f047489c150 0]
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: EVENTQ(7f04a30fe6f8): notify
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: THRD(7f04a30fe690) Dispatch [7f0472bf71a0 0]
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: EVENTQ(7f04a30fe6f8): notify
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: 784a2000:imap.example.com:NA:TellThreadToDie: close socket connection
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: 784a2000:imap.example.com:NA:CreateNewLineFromSocket: (null)
2001729280[7f047ae284c0]: destroying nsSocketTransport @7f047a5d4300
```

Again, it is not exactly informative to me.

**openssl log:**

```
openssl s_client -connect imap.mgr:993 -CAfile /etc/certs/cacert.pem 
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = DE, ST = NRW, L = Niederkassel, O = \C2\B5AC - Microsystem Accessory Consult, OU = IT, CN = CA
verify return:1
depth=0 C = DE, ST = NRW, L = Niederkassel, O = \C2\B5AC - Microsystem Accessory Consult, OU = IT, CN = imap.uac.microsult.de
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=DE/ST=NRW/L=Niederkassel/O=\xC2\xB5AC - Microsystem Accessory Consult/OU=IT/CN=imap.uac.microsult.de
   i:/C=DE/ST=NRW/L=Niederkassel/O=\xC2\xB5AC - Microsystem Accessory Consult/OU=IT/CN=CA
 1 s:/C=DE/ST=NRW/L=Niederkassel/O=\xC2\xB5AC - Microsystem Accessory Consult/OU=IT/CN=CA
   i:/C=DE/ST=NRW/L=Niederkassel/O=\xC2\xB5AC - Microsystem Accessory Consult/OU=IT/CN=CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=DE/ST=NRW/L=Niederkassel/O=\xC2\xB5AC - Microsystem Accessory Consult/OU=IT/CN=imap.uac.microsult.de
issuer=/C=DE/ST=NRW/L=Niederkassel/O=\xC2\xB5AC - Microsystem Accessory Consult/OU=IT/CN=CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 2967 bytes and written 615 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 730888566D757F19B38BF3CCD7A55CF44CBCD08B6763262CD36A2AA4230260DC
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 4DA397FA9EFF6EA3F2610291BFC3BDAA69DAA00F3B6787F06635F739A0D99EECCEFF715A3E22D66165E8CAADC968EEFD
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - 9d e1 fe 6a cf df 22 86-e8 2e c4 8b 4c 90 49 76   ...j..".....L.Iv
    0010 - e9 49 76 c9 4f 37 12 a3-4f b8 b5 44 18 e1 2b 64   .Iv.O7..O..D..+d
    0020 - af 01 7a 21 c7 b2 f2 84-17 fb a7 4d aa c3 73 dc   ..z!.......M..s.
    0030 - 91 b2 c5 ef d9 d8 2e 0a-bd f8 57 20 da ba bb 02   ..........W ....
    0040 - 1b a8 b1 21 0c f5 39 63-39 8c 90 51 48 3c 82 f2   ...!..9c9..QH<..
    0050 - a5 33 21 2e 23 f8 99 9c-0e 6f d0 67 99 8c 52 7b   .3!.#....o.g..R{
    0060 - 23 7a 13 45 5a 68 63 51-e3 e0 b6 ce fb 19 fa b4   #z.EZhcQ........
    0070 - 4b 6b 74 76 7d 5c 3d 55-83 a9 be 5a 11 46 65 14   Kktv}\=U...Z.Fe.
    0080 - dc de 9b ae ce 45 5e d8-eb 46 83 b2 a5 7b f0 ae   .....E^..F...{..
    0090 - f3 fe 2f a5 e4 8c 71 fa-6f 3f 10 61 7e f0 45 c5   ../...q.o?.a~.E.

    Start Time: 1459405125
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
* OK hermod Cyrus IMAP4 v2.2.13-Debian-2.2.13-14+lenny3 server ready
a1 LOGOUT
* BYE LOGOUT received
a1 OK Completed
read:errno=0
```

For STARTTLS on 143 the log is not different.

Comment: can you try the following and paste the output openssl s_client -connect yourserver.com:993

Comment: was there any change in the infrastructure? I had a similar problem where a cisco asa filtered out the starttls command

Comment: @Izac: no change, and openssl connects flawlessly, so there shouldn't be any problems in the transport layer.

Comment: Can you try a different mail client, maybe there is a Problem with some static linked ssl libraries that can't handle e.g SHA2. If that works we can narrow down the problem to your MUA

Comment: Using openssl s_client on port 143 I have a simple MUA. So it's obviously the MUA. The question is, whether it is probably less permissive for some good reason.

Answer (score -1):

Check the domain in the client's configuration.

- It needs to match the domain on the certificate.
- Check DNS resolution of the domain on the client.

There are a number of recent changes to both server and client software designed to resolve issues with SSL/TLS vulnerabilities.  It is possible one of these is causing an issue.  If your certificate has only a SHA-1 signature this may cause it to be rejected.

Comment: Signature is sha256withRSA. The server name matches CN. Well, the DN of both CA and server has a proper UTF8STRING, but AFAIK this should be compliant.

Comment: @Lars Hanke Thuderbird works will with my Dovecot/Exim4 servers.  I have reduced the available protocols, and have SMTP issues with some servers connecting from the Internet.  I've setup a blacklist to prevent advertising TLS to the problem domains.  You could try checking for protocol incompatibilities.